# Postgresql test JSON and delete

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a PGSQL database with a table that contains column containingJSON data along the lines of

```
{"kind":2,"msgid":102}
{"kind":99,"pid":"39s-8KeH306vhjzNta3Yrg,,","msgid":101}
...
```

Is it possible to write and execute DELETE statement along the lines of

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE data.kind = '99' AND data.pid = '39s-8KeH306vhjzNta3Yrg,,'?
```

where `data` happens to be the name of that particular column. I tried the above and got the error

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "data"
```

i.e. PGSQL is interpreting that as being the table data.  Clearly, the require syntax is different.  I'd be grateful to anyone who might be able to tell me what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"kind":99,"pid":"39s-8KeH306vhjzNta3Yrg,,","msgid":101}'::json))
select * from c where j->>'kind' = '99' and j->>'pid' = '39s-8KeH306vhjzNta3Yrg,,';
                            j
----------------------------------------------------------
 {"kind":99,"pid":"39s-8KeH306vhjzNta3Yrg,,","msgid":101}
(1 row)
```

then your statement will be:

```
delete from table where data->>'kind' = '99' and data->>'pid' = '39s-8KeH306vhjzNta3Yrg,,';
```

check json operators here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: A tip for anyone running into this post in quest of a similar thing - make sure that your JSON column in the pgsql table is of type JSONB!